# Green artifacts appearing on all movement

Tags: kubuntu, wayland, amdgpu

I recently installed Wayland on my Kubuntu 22.04 desktop, and apart from a couple minor hitches, it seemed to be working perfectly. However, after an update last night, it has re-introduced a problem I thought I had dealt with: green artifacts.

[Here's a video of them.](https://youtu.be/Dr979mu222E) Note that while the example video is using Minecraft, that's only to demonstrate them, and the artifacts appear across the entire system.

Technical notes: I'm using an AMD Radeon RX 570 GPU, with `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu 22.0.0-1ubuntu0.2` as the driver. The kernel version is 6.5.0-21-generic. Any other information can be provided upon request.

I thought this might have been a vsync issue, but ever since installing Wayland, there is zero screen tearing. To attempt to fix this issue when I used X, I would install non-LTS versions of Kubuntu, such as 23.10, however this did not help. The only thing that worked was enabling tear-free rendering (which was not at all tear-free), and then it only worked on 22.04. I think a driver or a kernel update may have ruined this.

**EDIT:** Okay, update, I had turned off my monitor for a few hours for various reasons, and when I turned it back on, the issue was gone. I'm really not sure what happened here, but I don't think that's going to be a consistent fix.

Comment: If xorg works fine, why not just use that?

Comment: Are the artifacts on the monitor or the framebuffer output? Basically, do the artifacts appear in an OBS recording? I also trust this is vanilla without shaders

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Because the screen tearing on X was unbearable and I couldn't fix it no matter what I tried.

Comment: @DanielT When I use OBS to record the screen and view the recording on my phone, there are no artifacts. I'm guessing this means the monitor is to blame. And yeah, no shaders, but as this happens in all applications I doubt that would make a difference.

Comment: Does lowering the resolution work around the problem?

Comment: It does not, no. I'd hook my computer up to a different monitor to be sure it's a monitor issue, but I don't have one spare, annoyingly.